# Wp Visual composser not showing

Tags: wordpress, html, visual-composer

Ive tried to uninstall and reinstal visual composer and i can´t seem to fix it, i can not edit front end because its simply not showing. i have the ken theme installed. when cheking the console i get this error, but i have little  to no expirence in programing and i don´t know what to make of it.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $template.get is not a function
    at n.html2element (composer-view.js:146)
    at n.render (composer-view.js:157)
    at n.appendShortcode (composer-view.js:534)
    at n.<anonymous> (composer-view.js:477)
    at load-scripts.php:112
    at Function.m.each.m.forEach (load-scripts.php:112)
    at n.addChild (composer-view.js:476)
    at n.addAll (composer-view.js:470)
    at _ (load-scripts.php:457)
    at m (load-scripts.php:457)
```

pls help.

Answer (score 1):

This basically means you have to update the visual composer. I have also experience a lot of issue. There are various option to solve this issue by modification of the code in visual composer file which is not recommended. So i personally suggest you to kindly update you visual composer then it works perfectly.

File to modify url is :

```
/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/backend.min.j‌​s
```

Code to replace is:

```
html2element: function(html) {
        var $template, attributes = {},
            template = html;
        $template = $(template(this.model.toJSON()).trim()), _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value
        }), this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()), this.setContent(), this.renderContent()
    },
```

Please only change the "html2element" function. Hope this works for you.

Thanks

Comment: the thing is i have the latest version available at artbees, witch is needed for the theme to work, what code modification can i do?

Comment: The code modification should have to be in template file which is quiet not good i think. See my modified answer.

Comment: Can´t seem to find that file, my folder name is js_composer_theme/assets/js, but i don´t have a dist folder,althoug i have a folder named backend with many files in it, but i dont want to edit any of them if i don´t know witch one it is

Comment: What is your visual composer version?

Comment: WPBakery Visual Composer (Artbees Modified Version) 4.5.3